# If $lk(v;K)$ is collapsible, then $K$ collapses to $del(v;K)$.

Tags: simplex, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-complex, convex-cone

I'm doing exercises about simplicial complexes and I'm stuck with one for which I'll first give some definitions.

Let $K$ a simplicial complex and $v\in K^0$ a $0$-simplex (vertex).

> The **star** of $v$ in $K$, $st(v;K)=\{\sigma\in K\mid \exists \tau\leq\sigma: v\in\tau\}$
>
> The **link** of $v$ in $K$, $lk(v;K)=\{\sigma\in st(v;K)\mid v\notin\sigma\}$.
>
> The **deletion** of $v$ y $K$, $del(v;K)=\{\sigma\in K\mid v\notin\sigma\}$.

The problem is the following:

> Show that if there is some $v\in K^0$ such that $lk(v;K)$ is collapsible, then $K$ collapses to $del(v;K)$.

The definition of collapse is a bit long, so I'll leave it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collapse_(topology)) if necessary.

I've been thinking of collapsing the star to the link using that the star is the simplicial cone over the link with respect to $v$. For each maximal simplex $\sigma$ and free face $\tau<\sigma$ of $lk(v;K)$ I can get a maximal simplex $v\sigma$ and a free face $v\tau<v\sigma$ of $st(v;K)$, hence I can make a collapse here.

The problem is that I don't see how to complete the proof. Once I perform this collapse, the new link is the first collapse of the original link, so I guess I should do parallel collapses in $lk(v;K)$ and in $K$ redefining the link of $v$ in $K$ at each step (the original link will remaing untouched in $K$).

I feel if I keep doing this, I'll end with $v$ conected by a $1$-simplex to a vertex of the original $lk(v;K)$, and then I can make the final collapse. An example of this would be the following picture where $K$ is a $3$-simplex. [image]

Comment: Haven't you just described a proof by induction? It looks good to me.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I was unsure of whether it was enough, but thanks!